# Нужна ли запятая перед "на"?

Tags: пунктуация

*...если не буду знать(,) на что способен.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

...если не буду знать, ***на что*** способен.

Это СПП с придаточным изъяснительным,  в качестве союзного слова используется падежная форма ***на что***.